# Jensen's inequality and convex Lagrangian

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, calculus-of-variations, jensen-inequality, variational-analysis

I was reading some lecture notes, and there was a following example that I didn't quite understand. If we have a following variational problem: $ \int_{a}^{b}f(u'(x))dx$ where the Lagrangian $f$ is a convex functional, $f \in C^1$, and $f$ depends only on the derivative of $u$. Without a proof, there was given that the global minimizer of this variational problem is the following function: $u:=\frac{\beta-\alpha}{b-a}x + \alpha$ where $u(a)=\alpha$ and $u(b)=\beta$ are the boundary conditions. How can I show that this makes sense? I tried using the Jensen's inequality but I can't get to the final answer.

Another possibility was using the convexity properties of the Lagrangian, but I didn't get to use any of the properties that were given for $u$.

I would like to derive this given answer but I am not sure how.

Comment: It would be nice if you could link these lecture notes to your post above, so we can retain the language , and try to understand why it was left without proof.

Comment: http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~rc207/pdf/Teaching/Spring2016/Cristoferi-Calculus_of_Variations-Lecture%20notes.pdf,  it is on the page 30, 3.3.2.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've just been seeing the PDF. So did you understand how the EL equation simplifies to $f'(u'(x)) = 0$? The given solution follows by solving that, so you need to explain if you did not get the EL simplified, or how that got solved to this (which is in ODE theory).

Comment: Thank you, I managed to show that it is a local minimizer (by inserting in the EL equation), and so far as I understood it is only a local minimizer? I am having difficulties by showing that it is the global minimizer as well. Does this follow from the fact that strictly convex functions only have global minima? Thank You for Your answer!

Comment: See, the point is that any *extremal* of the variational problem solves the Euler Lagrange equation. Now, even if we were to find a solution to the EL equation, we'd have to show that it is unique , and is a minimizer as well. That is done for us if the given function is strictly convex, because as you mention, strictly convex functions have a unique minimum. The example following that "The non-convex case" explains that better.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $b>a$ and so $\frac{1}{b-a}>0.$

Since $f$ is convex, Jensen's integral inequality holds: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality - **Form involving a probability density function**).

As $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{b-a}dx$ is a probability measure $f ( 
\int_a^b u'(x)\frac{1}{b-a}dx) \leq \int_{a}^{b} f(u'(x))\frac{1}{b-a} dx$ with equality, if $u'$ is constant, so if $u$ is a linear function. The linear function that satisfies the boundary condition $u(a)=\alpha$ and $u(b)=\beta$ is $u(x) = \frac{\beta - \alpha}{b-a}(x - a) + \alpha.$

So this $u$ is a global minimizer, but if $f$ is only convex, uniqueness is not guaranteed. It is however guaranteed, when $f$ is strictly convex.